How to handle intermediate observations in Weibull Models (censoring)
I'm currently working on updating previously created Weibull Models on component failure.
The Situation:

I have data available, that shows if a component of a machine has been exchanged (mainly during inspections but sometimes the machine gets stopped and the component gets exchanged because of severe damage) because of one specific failure mode.
The data contains a serial number of the component, the lifetime in hours up to the date and if the event happened or not.

Now I am unsure how to treat the observations of one specific component with a unique serial number between installation and removal. For example: Parts are often inspected two to four times before they fail. (data: |---0---0---0---1). Have these "0" points now to be included in the model data as right-censored events? I understood right censored observations as events, where we do not know what happens to the component later.
My view would be that the observations are not taken into account if we know the exact time of exchange (no inspection/exchange bc of severe damage). If a component was replaced during an inspection, it is interval-censored data. In this case, the replacement would be between the last inspection without an event and the event.
The previously created Weibull Model contains all intermediate observations as right-censored observations and all observations with failure as occurred events.
I did a lot of research, but I couldn't find a clear answer in this case. If you have literature on this case, you'd help me out if you share it.
Thanks in advance!
